# Why does Incredible Hulk TV series end up so abruptly?

Tags: ending, the-incredible-hulk-tv

This is about the 70s show.

When you watch the last episode, something feels wrong, it doesn't look like an ending at all. Rather, something they decided to make as ending at last minute.

So, what does one has to understand with that weird ending?

Comment: Could you expand on this, why doesn't it look like an ending? What's abrupt about it?

Comment: *"CBS initially did not want to continue with the series for the fall of 1981... With seven new episodes already filmed, Johnson tried unsuccessfully to persuade Sheppard to buy more episodes; Bill Bixby talked to other networks about picking up the show, but no deal could be reached in time to keep the series in production. Nevertheless, CBS aired those seven episodes sporadically during the 1981-82 season. Due to the sudden cancellation, the producers never had a chance to plan a series finale, in which David Banner would have been successfully cured of the Hulk."*

Comment: TV shows having endings is a fairly recent evolution.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Basically, he comes to an empty city, meet a girl, do something with her then he leaves, no farewell at all (lol). Well that's a bit summarized but that's my feeling. I was expecting something like "I'll be back" or something :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Paulie_D noted in the comments, the show was abruptly cancelled partway through production of Season 5. The seven completed episodes from that season were aired, but the producers simply didn't have the opportunity to develop a proper finale, which is why the final episode ends the same way all the other episodes do: with Banner fleeing to resume his search for a cure.

However, between 1988 and 1990, a trilogy of made-for-TV movies were released that continued the series' storyline and eventually gave it a proper ending. So the reason it doesn't feel like an ending is that it quite literally is *not* an ending - you have to watch the movies (or at the very least, the third one) to see how Banner's story ends.

Comment: Okay I see, I heard of these TV-made episodes, I need to watch them !

Comment: Kind of a weird question, but since this is a US TV show, should we be using US terms? E.g. "Season 5" instead of "Series 5"?

Comment: @Kevin Just realised I used "series" in the first sentence and "season" in the second sentence... good catch.